# Custom route not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I believe that I already did all the important thing to set up the custom route in codeigniter but I still don't know why I always get 404 error.

The current url I can access is: `http://localhost:8080/project/api/profile_test/`

And I want to rewrite it as: `http://localhost:8080/project/api/users/`

I've added this code in the `route.php` but still not working: `$route[‘users’] = 'profile_test';`

My `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I already set the `AllowOverride All` and remove the `index.php` in `$config['index_page'] = '';`. But still not working.

I’m almost 8 hours for this with this little thing and I need help to the one who knows it.
What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: make sure there is no mistake for `profle_test` vs `profile_test`

Comment: And also `$route[‘users’] = 'api/profile_test';`

Comment: @shourav yes it's I don't have any mistake.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i already tried that but not working

Comment: ^ any mistake `‘users’` vs `'users'`

Comment: @shourav still no

Comment: `$route['api/users'] = 'api/profile_test';` tried this??

Comment: @shourav still not working.

Comment: What is the name of your controller and method?

Comment: @Don'tPanic my controller name is `profile_test` class and the method is `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter, a route consists of 3 parts:

- the URL
- the controller name
- the method name

[The docs explain it well](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

So, if your project's root is `http://localhost:8080/`, for a URL like `project/api/users/`, to be handled by a controller (located in `application/controllers/`) called `Profile_test` and a method called `index`, you would need a route like:

```
$route['/project/api/users'] = 'profile_test/index';
```

Note that the controller file and class must be capitalised, [as described in the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html), so for example `controllers/Profile_test.php`.

If your project's root is `http://localhost:8080/project`, you would change that to:

```
$route['/api/users'] = 'profile_test/index';
```

If your controller is located in a subdirectory like `application/controllers/api/`, you would change that to:

```
$route['/project/api/users'] = 'api/profile_test/index';
```

Also make sure you are using normal single quotes.  Some of the code you include in your question includes 'smart' quotes: `$route[‘users’]` which will not work in PHP.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Does your CI log show anything?

Comment: I think it will be like this - ```$route['api/users'] = 'api/profile_test/index';```

Comment: What is your `base_url`, I mean what is the root of your project?  I assumed it was at `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: The root is ` $config['base_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";`

Comment: Is your controller named with capital `P`, so `application/controllers/Profile_test.php` (with matching capitalised class name)? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html

Comment: Okay I'll check

Comment: Your .htaccess has been modified from [the default Codeigniter one](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html).  I don't know why you did that or if you need it changed.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes you help me to understand how it works and its working fine now.